Autocorrelation of Binary Random Variable
Let $X_i$ be a random variable that takes either the value $+1$ or $-1$. Suppose that if the previous value $X_{i-1}$ is $x\in \left\{ -1, 1\right\}$, then $X_i$ also takes value $x$ with probability $p$, and it takes the value $-x$ with probability $q=1-p$.
Question: Can we calculate the autocorrelation function of $X_i$ at a given lag $k\in \mathbb N$?
My approach: We want to calculate $\operatorname{corr}(X_i, X_{i+k})$. For simplicity, let's first consider $k=1$.
We have that $\operatorname{corr}(X_i, X_{i+1}) = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_{i+1})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X_i) \operatorname{var}(X_{i+1})}}$
so let us begin by trying to calculate the quantity:
$$\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_{i+1}) = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_i X_{i+1} \right] - \operatorname{E}\left[ X_i \right] \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i+1} \right].$$
We have
$$X_i X_{i+1} = \begin{cases}
                    X_i^2 & \text{ with probability } p  \\
                    -X_i^2 & \text{ with probability } q
                        \end{cases}$$
and therefore:
$$\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i X_{i+1} | X_i\right] = pX_i^2 - qX_i^2 = p - q.$$
Moreover, it holds that
$$\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i+1}\right] = p - q.$$
And therefore, by plugging into the earlier equation, we should have:
$$\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_{i+1}) = (p - q) - (p - q)^2$$
Next, let's compute the variance:
$$\operatorname{var}\left[ X_{i+1}\right] = \operatorname{var}\left[ X_i\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i}^2\right] - \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i}\right]^2 = 1 - (p-q)^2.$$
If all of that is correct, then we should have:
$$\operatorname{corr}(X_i, X_{i+1}) = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_{i+1})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X_i) \operatorname{var}(X_{i+1})}} = \frac{(p - q) - (p - q)^2}{1 - (p-q)^2}$$
But this is impossible because it gives values $< -1$, for example with $p=0.1$. Therefore, something above must be wrong. Please help me correct my calculation :-)

You don't have sufficient information to calculate the variance.

Your error is when you say

Moreover, it holds that
$\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i+1}\right] = p - q.$

Assuming $X_0=+1$ or $-1$ with equal probability, you have $$\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i+1}\right] = 0.$$
Even if there were a different distribution for $X_0$, the distribution for $X_i$ would converge towards $+1$ and $-1$ with equal probability as $i$ increases and thus $\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i\right]\to 0$, so long as $0<p<1$.
$\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i+1}\right] = 0$ would make $\operatorname{var}\left[ X_{i+1}\right] = \operatorname{var}\left[ X_i\right] =1$, and $\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_{i+1}) = p - q$ and $$\operatorname{corr}(X_i, X_{i+1}) = p - q,$$ which will be between $-1$ and $1$ as you might hope.
For longer lags, you should get $$\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_{i+k}) = \operatorname{corr}(X_i, X_{i+k}) = (p - q)^k,$$ which converges towards $0$ as $k$ increases, so long as $0<p<1$.

Nothing in the problem implies that a large number limit is appropriate.

@Paul: $\operatorname{E}\left[ X_i\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[ X_{i+1}\right]$ would imply that both are $0$ (or that $p=1$).

sure, but there's no reason to expect that.

Let random variables $Z_1,Z_2,...$ be i.i.d. $Z$, such that $P(Z=1)=p, P(Z=-1)=q=1-p,$ so we have $X_{i+1}=Z_{i+1}\,X_i$, and $$\begin{align}X_{i+k}&=(Z_{i+k}\cdot\cdot\cdot Z_{i+1}) X_i=(Z_{i+k}\cdot\cdot\cdot Z_1)X_0, \quad k=1,2,3,...\end{align}$$
If the $Z_i$ are also independent of the $X_i$, then we have
$$\begin{align}E(X_{i+k})&=E(Z)^k\,E(X_i)=(p-q)^kE(X_i)\\ E(X_iX_{i+k})&=E(Z)^k\,E(X_i^2)=(p-q)^k\end{align}$$
yielding
$$\begin{align}
\text{corr}(X_i,X_{i+k})&={(p-q)^k - (p-q)^kE(X_i)^2  \over \sqrt{1-E(X_i)^2} \sqrt{1-E(X_{i+k})^2}}\\[2ex]
&=(p-q)^k\,\sqrt{{ 1-E(X_i)^2\over 1-E(X_{i+k})^2}}\\[2ex]
&=(p-q)^k\,\sqrt{{ 1-(p-q)^iE(X_0)^2\over 1-(p-q)^{i+k}E(X_{0})^2}}\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$
